# SOAP, JAXB marshalling behavior

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, wsimport

I have a WSDL spec, using `wsimport` to generate client code. (as I've done numerous times before).

Now, one of types in xsd:

```
<xs:complexType name="Credential">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="UID" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="UIDBranch" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="PWD" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Signature" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

And corresponding java binding:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Credential", namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/...", propOrder = {
  "uid",
  "uidBranch",
  "pwd",
  "signature"
})
public class Credential {

  @XmlElementRef(name = "UID", namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/...", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
  protected JAXBElement<String> uid;
  @XmlElementRef(name = "UIDBranch", namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/...", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
  protected JAXBElement<String> uidBranch;
  @XmlElementRef(name = "PWD", namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/...", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
  protected JAXBElement<String> pwd;
  @XmlElementRef(name = "Signature", namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/...", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
  protected JAXBElement<String> signature; 

  ... the rest: getters/setters
```

When in a request an element of this type happens to look like:

```
<ns2:Credentials>
   <ns4:string>login</ns4:string>
   <ns4:string>password</ns4:string>
   <ns4:string>signature</ns4:string>
</ns2:Credentials>
```

But it loses names of elements inside the type, the fragment above should look like this:

```
<ns2:Credentials>                                                               
  <ns4:UID>login</ns4:UID>                                                             
  <ns4:PWD>password</ns4:PWD>                                                             
  <ns4:Signature>signature</ns4:Signature>
</ns2:Credentials>
```

Why can it be and how to force client to behave in the correct way?

**Update**
Credentials object is created like this (`of` is `ObjectFactory`):

```
Credential cr = of.createCredential()
cr.setUID(of.createString(login))
cr.setPWD(of.createString(password))
cr.setSignature(of.createString(sign))
```

Comment: How do you construct the `Credentials` object?

Comment: @lexicore Updated in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get

```
<ns4:string>login</ns4:string>
```

because you use `of.createString(login)`. Use something like `of.createUID(...)` if you want `ns4:UID`.

The thing is, `JAXBElement<String>` has a string value (ex. login) but also the name of the element (`getValue()` and `getName()` respectively). This name is what gives the XML element its name. The `ObjectFactory` generated by `wsimport`/`xjc` usually contains methods to generate such `JAXBElement` instances. These `createFoo`-methods take value as input and wrap them in `JAXBElement`s with the corresponding XML names. So when you use `createString`, you actually say you want `string` as element name. `String` in `createString` is for element name, not for the value type.

So your `ObjectFactory` should also have methods like `createUID`, `createPWD`, `createSignature` etc. Use those methods instead of `createString`.

By the way, have you actually tried debugging it? The whole story would be pretty obvious if you've taken a look at the source code of `ObjectFactory`, any reason to avoid that?